# Can I run a copper pipe for water in an exterior wall without it freezing in the winter?

Tags: plumbing, exterior

I would like to install a new hose bib on the exterior wall of my house, to be accessed on the deck.  Currently, there is a hose bib on the lower level (underneath the deck) straight down from where I would like to put this new one.  Is there a risk of a pipe this length freezing in the winter, if it is in the middle of the insulated exterior wall?  Should I use extra pipe insulation to prevent it from freezing, or with it being in a wall with insulation be enough?  I'm in Virginia, so it doesnt get that cold, but it does freeze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you able to turn off the water supply to the lower faucet?  And is this what you would normally do in cold weather?

If so, you could turn off the water, open both faucets and the water in the pipe would drain out the lower faucet.  You would be in exactly the same position as you were before in terms of freezing.

Answer (score 11):

Use a [frost-proof sillcock](http://www.woodfordmfg.com/woodford/HowAFaucet/HowaFaucetWorks.html).  It will shut off the water 12 inches into the wall (which is probably on the inside of the wall for you), and the water on the outside of the shutoff will drain as long as there is no hose attached.

[image: Frost-proof sillcock]